# The Flutter Hashmap<String, List<CustomObject>> is overwriting the List type in the Hashmap on every add

Tags: flutter, dart, aws-amplify

The Flutter Hashmap<String, List > is overwritting the List type in the Hashmap on every single unique Key. So basically the code looks like:

```
    HashMap<String, List<Jobs> > ElementJobMap = new HashMap<String, List<Jobs> >();

    for (int i = 0; i < _JobsList.length; i++) {
      String Key = _JobsList[i].elementID.toString();
      if (ElementJobMap.containsKey(Key)) {
        if (Key == _JobsList[i].elementID.toString()) {
          
            ElementJobMap.update(Key, (value) {
            value.add(_JobsList[i]);
            return value;
          });

        }
      } else {

        ElementJobMap[Key] = tmpList;

      }
    }
```

So if there are two different String keys and each key has a unique list filled with several values in each. If I write to the List every instance is updated and so it is all the same data. Should be noted this code might have pointless stuff in it, but I've just been spitballing for awhile now.

Comment: seems you need [groupListsBy](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/IterableExtension/groupListsBy.html)

Comment: It seems promising for sure. Thank you for the quick response. @pskink

Comment: or [groupBy](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/groupBy.html) top level function, the docs say: *"Groups the elements in values by the value returned by key.

Returns a map from keys computed by key to a list of all values for which key returns that key. The values appear in the list in the same relative order as in values."*

Comment: groupListsBy resolved this question. In truth, I ended up using a stream to make it all work though since it needed to be observed.

Answer (score 0):

> ElementJobMap[Key] = tmpList;

You seem to be adding *the exact same list instance* as a base of *every* entry. Then you add to this single instance. If you want your hashmap to hold a different list instance for every key, you need to actually create one.

That said, you should probably look into grouping methods provided through packages, there is no point in trying to do it manually.